# RestFul java проблема с подключением CSS

Tags: java, rest

Огромная проблема. Есть Java Restful web service построенный на jax-rs 2.0. Есть статические html страницы которые загружаются через web.xml.

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>startPage</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/pages/index.html</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>startPage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/pages/mainFrame.html</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>account</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/account</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Вот ссылка на ресурсы в Html странице:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css" type="text/css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SnackLanguage/resources/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Snack Language</title>
</head>
```

А вот сама структура проекта:

[image]

А вот то что выдает браузер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все время выпадает вот такая ошибка:`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

Кто может помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На последнем изображении в консоли браузера имеется следующее предупреждение:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/SnackLanguage/resources/css/index.css".

Оно гласит, что ресурс по данному адресу, распознаётся как каскадные таблицы стилей, но при этом передаётся с `mime-type="text/html"`
Для каскадных таблиц стилей корректным `mime-type` будет соответствовать `text/css`

Переходим в предоставленный Вами web.xml и убеждаемся, что в соответствующем `<mime-mapping>` mime-type для расширения css указан неверно, и соответствует mime-type, указанному в консоли браузера.

```
  ...
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  ...
```

Заменяем `text/html` на `text/css`:

```
  ...
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  ...
```

Запускаем приложение и проверяем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, стили применились.
Проблема была в типе данных указанных при отдаче css.

Заодно посоветую в верстке закрывать все одинарные теги:
И вместо

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Лучше указывать:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: C MIME типом разобрался и стили подключились, спасибо! Только изображения из стилей не подтягиваются. И кстати закрыв одинарный тег с кодировкой, оно не сработало для исправления непонятных символов на странице.

Comment: @MainStar, непонятные символы на странице - это неверная кодировка и насколько я предполагаю она неверная изначально, поскольку по умолчанию локаль в JVM - ISO-8859-1. И это совершенно другая история связанная с деплоем, настройкой конфигураций запуска в IDE, настройкой сервера приложений и в небольшой степени с самим приложением.

Comment: @MainStar, поэтому я советую создать другой вопрос, в котором описать что у вас при разработке веб-приложения проблемы с кодировкой, написать каким сервером приложений вы пользуетесь и приложить web.xml в виде текста, конфигурацию запуска приложения в IDE..по ситуации возможно еще чтото понадобится, ну и в качестве наглядного примера можете показать что получается с вашей страницей

Comment: @MainStar, даная тема сильно выходит за рамки текущего вопроса

Comment: Все, понял, тогда большое спасибо!